# Regex python. Как вытащить определенное слово из текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть у кого регулярка которая из текста вытащит все @usermention

т.е Текст

```
User: @username
User2: @username2
```

Регулярка должна вернуть @username @username2

Готовая регулярка чтобы использовать ее в коде.

Comment: это гораздо проще сделать циклом по словам.

Comment: Это весь текст такой или там что-то другое может тоже встречаться?

Comment: `@\w+` - попробуйте эту

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, без регулярки:

```
text = 'User: @username User2: @username2'.split(' ')
for tx in text:
    if tx.startswith("@"):
        print(tx)
```

Или так:

```
text = 'User: @username User2: @username2'.split(' ')
u_name = [x for x in text if x.startswith("@")]
print(u_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл

```
r"@(\w{4,})"
```